# which approach is best to search object in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, processing-efficiency

I've sorted following ways to search for an object in array. 
This question has been asked like countless times but I want to know which of the best from following ways. If there's another I'd like to know that too.

**Using `$.grep()`**

```
function is_in_array(arr,element){
    var result = $.grep(arr, function(e){ return e.id == element; });
    return result.length;
}
```

Above function returns length of array.

- 0 when element not present
- 1 when element present
- length > 1 if more elements with same value present

**using lookup object**

```
var lookup = {};
for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    lookup[array[i].id] = array[i];
}
```

This way I don't need to traverse entire array each time. I'd just check for `lookup[id]` instead.

**for loop in traditional way**

```
function in_array(array, id) {
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        if(array[i].id === id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

to check if element exists, i'd call `in_array(arr,element)`.

Which approach is best ? Question seriously sounds duplicate and it is but I just want to make sure which is best from these three only.

**Update**

Array will contain objects like --

```
var arr = [];
var nameObj = {};

nameObj.label = "somename";
nameObj.id = 123;
arr.push(nameObj);
.
.
.
```

Comment: the lookup is the fastest to execute more than once.

Comment: iterate the array with a for loop, and do `return key in array[i]`

Comment: @adeneo- that only checks presence, not values, it hits inhered props,  and it's slow to do a loop-de-loop when just a loop will work.

Comment: @adeneo yea like mentioned in last method ? dandavis i also felt that'd be good for multiple lookups.

Comment: I think this is going to depend on what `element` is. What exactly are you looking for in the array? a plain javascript object? what are you matching on? a value in the object? the object as a whole?

Comment: I'd do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f3kHw/) ??

Comment: @KevinB I've updated question with those details. adeno it is somehow similar to third approach mentioned. Right ? And what about `grep`, is it a good way or expensive ?

Comment: The lookup would definitely be the better way to go if you need to do this multiple times and the array is rather large and doesn't change much, otherwise the traditional for loop would be better.

Comment: @KevinB So I guess lookup it is ! :) I still don't know why `$.grep` is not suggested yet. It's given in jqeury and looks ok too. If somehow there's a need to remove duplicate objects then that's also possible. I'll get those duplicate objects from array.

Comment: Well, $.grep is basically the traditional method, only it doesn't stop when it finds a match, it instead goes through them all looking for matches, then checks how many were found. You don't care how many are found, you just want to know if at least 1 was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use a combination of `JSON` (for comparison) and the `Array.filter` method:

```
var findvalue = JSON.stringify([somevalue]),
    ,found = [array].filter(
               function(a){return JSON.stringify(a) === findvalue;}).length
;
// found > 0 means: findvalue found
```

A [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/z9p2c/) example
More about `Array.filter` and a shim for older browsers [**@MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: +1 for fiddle. And all comments and answer are valuable and improved my knowledge. Going to accept this answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method instead of a loop:

```
var lookup=array.map(function(e){return e.id;});
```

(Not supported in IE 8)

Comment: You could also use jQuery's implementation of the same for IE8 support: `$.map(function(e){ return e.id; });` it shouldn't be any faster or any more efficient, and doesn't really look any cleaner imo.